# Use .getopenfile name to create hyperlink and also use as file path to link cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel macro that asks a user to select a file using `.GetOpenFilename`.  Once the user has selected the file, the macro creates a hyperlink for said file.  The next step I would like the macro to complete is to use that selected file to create links into a summary sheet where the macro lives.  I have it set up now and it works if I pre determine the file name but it will be different every time so I want to use the file that the user selected.  The file that the user selects is from a template, I have already named the cells that I need to link in the template to make it easier.  The code I have is below,  I think what I need is to replace the `[my_Filename]` with whatever the proper code is.

```
Dim rngDestin0 As Range
Dim rngDestin1 As Range
Dim rngDestin2 As Range
Dim rngDestin3 As Range


Dim my_FileName As String
Dim fPath As String, fName As String
fPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
fName = Split(fPath, Application.PathSeparator)(UBound(Split(fPath, 
Application.PathSeparator)))

my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

Set rngDestin0 = Range("SO_Number").Resize(1).Offset(-1)

With Range("A1").Hyperlinks
    .Delete
    .Add Anchor:=rngDestin0, Address:=fPath, TextToDisplay:=fName
End With



'SALES ORDER NUMBER LINK
Set rngDestin1 = Range("SO_Number").Resize(1).Offset(-1)
rngDestin1.Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[my_FileName]tab1'!S_O_N"

'JOB NUMBER LINK
Set rngDestin2 = Range("A").Resize(1).Offset(-1)
rngDestin2.Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[my_FileName]tab1'!Job_Num"

'START DATE LINK
Set rngDestin3 = Range("B").Resize(1).Offset(-1)
rngDestin3.Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[my_FileName]tab1'!Job_Start"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the file they selected in a variable, `my_FileName`,  so concatenate that into each string where required:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "='[" & my_FileName & " ]tab1'!Job_Start"
```

Comment: Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
Method 'FormulaR1C1' of object 'Range' failed

Comment: The workbook needs to be open for the formula to return anything other than #Name?

Comment: I am using .Formula now  in the above. Also, check that the value of my_FileName is not False when the error occurs.

Comment: Still getting the same error...my_FileName is not false.

Comment: You get the same error of R1C1 with .Formula ? On that line?

Comment: It is the same line but now it says...

"Method'Formula' of object 'Range' failed

Comment: Does your chosen workbook have a named range Job_Start in sheet tab1?

Comment: Yes it does.  I made sure everything is named properly.